# Instantiating nested classes shorthand

Tags: c#

I am trying to Fill a list of objects in this format so that it matches my JSON.NEt output for a needed API. But I am getting a NullReferenceException on the whole block starting with .Add()...Am I missing something?

```
 foreach(var item in emailsToUpload.payload)
    {
        hubPayload.Add(new HubEmailItem()
        {
            email = item.Email, properties = 
            { new HubEmailTuple() { property = "date", value = (DateTime.Now).ToString("d") },
              new HubEmailTuple() { property = "other property", value = "other value" }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Update:**

```
public class HubEmailItem
{
    public String email { get; set; }
    public List<HubEmailTuple> properties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a `null` object in your `emailsToUpload.payload` collection?

Comment: Are you sure `hubPayload` is initialized ?

Comment: Did you instantiate hubPayload ?

Comment: List<HubEmailItem> hubPayload = new List<HubEmailItem>(); It looks like this.

Comment: what's the type of `HubEmailItem.properties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this syntax with generic lists like this.

```
properties = 
        { new HubEmailTuple() { property = "date", value = (DateTime.Now).ToString("d") },
          new HubEmailTuple() { property = "other property", value = "other value" }
        }
```

You should add a `new List<HubSpotEmailTuple>`

```
properties =  new List<HubSpotEmailTuple>
        { new HubEmailTuple() { property = "date", value = (DateTime.Now).ToString("d") },
          new HubEmailTuple() { property = "other property", value = "other value" }
        }
```

Note: This is valid:

```
int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
```

But this is not:

```
// wrong
List<int> a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};

// correct
List<int> a =  new List<int> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
```

Take a look at documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You sir, are correct. It just worked. Thanks! Will accept in a min.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction by the way I was wrong about this,I just noticed.you can only use this syntax when you initilazing your array: `int[] a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};` so this is invalid: `int[] a; a = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};` just keep in mind :))

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could throw this exception in case the List is initialized is one of the items you are iterating through. You are using the Email property and it seems that one of the items is null and is causing the exception.

```
email = item.Email //causes NullReferenceException when item is null
```

You can check if this is indeed true by setting a conditional breakpoint at the first curly brace of the foreach loop that will be triggered when `item == null` is true.

Comment: This is what I meant by my comment. +1.

Comment: It stops on the very first item, and email is not null; I point at it during debug and it has a value.

Comment: What about breaking up the creation and adding of the new HubEmailItem in the collection into separate statements to see if the Add or the construction causes the problem.